# meaning of invoking default constructor

Tags: java

I have a homework already done, my teacher get back to me said I need to invoking the default constructor, I am not quite understand what is the difference, can anyone help to explain it to me?
Thanks

here is my original code

```
public Triangle()
    {
        this.side1 = 1.0;
        this.side2 = 1.0;
        this.side3 = 1.0;
    }
```

and the code that my teacher want me to change

```
public Triangle()
    {
        this(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    }
```

Comment: Calling `this(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` removes unnecessary code duplication, making it more maintainable and less bug prone.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you already have a constructor like this:

```
public Triangle(double s1, double s2, double s3) {
    this.side1 = s1;
    this.side2 = s2;
    this.side3 = s3;
}
```

then your two examples are functionally identical. However it is always good practice to call this constructor instead of repeating yourself with another three assignments.

---

As a side note, "invoking the default" constructor is referring to invoking the constructor with no parameters, either through creating an instance or calling `this()` through another constructor.

Comment: Hi Henry, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have another constructor exactly what you have display. That mean for the good practice of programming, I shoudn't to repeat this.side to ref to 1.0 ? Am I getting on right track? Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly, like I said, they are the same, but it makes the code more readable especially if it's a more complex example than yours. Also allows you to change the behaviour of all constructors by just changing the base one.